# Modsecurity REGEX has not effect?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, firewall, regex

```
 [25/Oct/2016:09:35:16 +0200] [demo.localhost.me/sid#555555a697d8][rid#5555572958d8][/XXXXX.php][2]
 Warning. Pattern match "([\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\+\\=\\{\\}\\[\\]\\|\\:\\;\"\\'\\\xc2\xb4\\\xe2\x80\x99\\\xe2\x80\x98\\`\\<\\>].*?){5,}" 
at ARGS_NAMES:MtCons-NSOPE3-MtCons12-HJIBE-2808-J103048-2016. [file "/XXXXX/apc22/virtual
/XXXX/crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"] [line "159"] [id "981173"] [rev "2"] [msg "Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded"] 
[data "Matched Data: - found within ARGS_NAMES:MtCons-NSOPE3-MtCons12-HJIBE-2808-J103048-2016: MtCons-NSOPE3-MtCons12-HJIBE-2808-J103048-2016"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"]
```

Hi,

I'm trying to remove this false postive with regex, but it seem impossible?

I am familiar with ModSecurity whitelist but regex for this "ARGS_NAMES" seem not work.

I have tried:

```
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981173 "!ARGS_NAMES:/MtCons.*/"

SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981173 "!ARGS_NAMES:/MtCons.*/gm"
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
 SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981173 "!ARGS_NAMES:/MtCons.*/"
```